# How to put custom variables into PHP error logs

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging

I want to include certain server information in the error logs. Is there a way to force PHP to include `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` (or any other variable) into the log entry? So for example the log would be:

> [08-Apr-2015 16:58:33] 125.60.12.1 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined
>   function a() in /index.php on line 5

instead of

> [08-Apr-2015 16:58:33] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   a() in /index.php on line 5

Comment: This depends on your webserver. What is it?

Comment: It runs on centOS 5.6 is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you running PHP with a web server like Apache? if so, what version of Apache?

Comment: The error logs are part of the web server. Apache saves the IP address by default. For the other severs it depends on the configuration.

Comment: Changed title, slightly formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error handler**

The best way to get more information for an error is to create your own error handler

This example outputs the standard error information plus all variables in use at the time.

This particular function will contain sensitive information so we added a line to remove things like passwords.

```
$dev=true;  //dev pc

function error_function($err_level,$err_msg,$err_file,$err_line,$err_context)
{
    global $dev;
    $err_stg="<br />
    ############################<br />
    <b>Error level:</b> $err_level<br />
    <b>Message:</b>     $err_msg<br />
    <b>File:</b>        $err_file<br />
    <b>On line:</b>     $err_line<br />
    ############################<br /><br />";

    //convert array to string
    $err_stg.=serialize($err_context);

    //remove sensitive information
    $pos=strpos($err_stg,'MYSQL_PASSWORD');
    if($pos){ $err_stg=substr($err_stg,0,$pos).substr($err_stg,$pos+40); }

    if($dev)  //if on dev pc echo error
    {
        echo $err_stg;
    }
    else //if live on site save error to file
    {
        error_log($err_stg,3,"error_file_secret.html");
    }
}
```

Set this function as the error handler

```
set_error_handler("error_function",E_ALL);
```

Customise this function to suit your needs.

Comment: That's true, php will however revert back to the default error output, which should be enough to diagnose fatal errors.